# When is suitable to use present simple / present progressive in the next context?

Tags: questions, progressive-aspect

When is correct to use structure no. 1, and when is suitable to use structure no. 2?

> 1. Which city **do** you **live** in?
> 2. Which city **are** you **living** in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it may sound counterintuitive the present continuous (structure 2) applies to a short period around the present moment, whereas the simple present (structure 1) applies to past, present, and future. Check [this verb chart in SE ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another). That’s why you say *I am a man/a woman/French/a teacher* and not  * *I am being a man/a woman/French/a teacher*. And you say *I write poems* (meaning regularly as a hobby or for a living) but you say *please don´t disturb, I’m writing a poem (right now).*

So if you ask *in which city are you living in?* you imply you know the person has recently moved to another city, or usually moves from city to city frequently. You could say, for instance, *I’m told you’ve moved again, where are you living now?*

If you have no idea whether the person moves home frequently, or know that the person has been living in the same place for quite some time it is more natural to ask *which city do you live in?* or simply *where do you live?*